# Condition with OR operator

Tags: if-statement

I have a condition Javascript like that :

```
if(a!= undefined || b!= undefined){
   do something
}
```

if the `a` value is undefined I can't enter the condition (that's good) but if the `a` value is not undefined BUT the `b` value is undefined, I still enter in the condition...

Comment: Don't want want logical AND then if you want to ensure both are not undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an AND condition:

```
if (a != undefined && b != undefined) {
    do something
}
```